Is there a term for a countour integral that disregards direction?
Is there a name for integration of the form $\oint_\gamma f(z) |dz|$?
In other words, the integral that only takes into account the length of the contour and the values of the function but not the direction of integration?
For instance, the integral $\oint_{\text{unit circle}} 1/z |dz|=0$.
If so, do the computer algebra systems allow to compute such integrals?

that is the line integral of a scalar field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral

@CarloBeenakker but the article says ${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\oint _{L}{\frac {1}{z}},dz&=\int _{0}^{2\pi }{\frac {1}{e^{it}}}ie^{it},dt=i\int _{0}^{2\pi }e^{-it}e^{it},dt\&=i\int _{0}^{2\pi }dt=i(2\pi -0)=2\pi i.\end{aligned}}}$

@Anixx You are looking at the wrong subsection. You want to look at the one under "Line integral of a scalar field" like Carlo mentioned.

@Wojowu thanks for the clarification. It seems, in Mathematica, LineIntegral does the job.

That is the line integral of a scalar field.  Consider a parameterization $\gamma(t)$, $a<t<b$ of the contour $C$, then
$$\int_C f(z) \, dz=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) \, dt,$$
while
$$\int_C f(z)\,|dz|=\int_a^b f(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|\,dt.$$

Thanks for the pointing out the term. I accept mainly for pointing the term for it.

Still, it seems, LineIntegrate[1/z, z \[Element] Circle[]] cannot be evaluated in Mathematica.

LineIntegrate[Abs[z], z \[Element] Circle[]] also does not work.

I edited in your comment to make the answer self-contained.  I hope that that was all right.

@Anixx, whether Mathematica can compute these objects seems like a separate question, probably for MathematicaSE rather than MO.

@LSpice paradoxically, it is the line integral of vector field that gives correct results in Mathematica: LineIntegrate[1/(x + I   y), {x, y} \[Element] Circle[]] LineIntegrate[1/Abs[x + I   y], {x, y} \[Element] Circle[]]. Weird.

@Anixx in higher dimension the analogous concept is that of an integral varifold.

In Calculus textbooks
$$\int_\gamma f(z)|dz|$$
is called the line integral of the first kind,
In arbitrary dimension it is frequently written as
$$\int_\gamma f(x)ds,$$
where $ds$ is the length element,
while
$$\int_\gamma f(z)dz$$
is the integral of the second kind. It is the same as the integral of a $1$-form,
$$\int_\gamma pdx+qdy.$$

I think it depends on the textbook.  In Larson and Edwards - Calculus, they are just called "line integral" and "line integral of a vector field".
